# ANTLR grammar to recognize DIGIT keys and INTEGERS too

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm trying to create an ANTLR grammar to parse sequences of keys that optionally have a repeat count. For example, `(a b c r5)` means "repeat keys a, b, and c five times."

I have the grammar working for `KEYS : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')`.

But when I try to add digit keys `KEYS : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')` with an input expression like `(a 5 r5)`, the parse fails on the middle 5 because it can't tell if the 5 is an INTEGER or a KEY. (Or so I think; the error messages are difficult to interpret "NoViableAltException").

I have tried these grammatical forms, which work ('r' means "repeatcount"):

```
repeat : '(' LETTERKEYS INTEGER ')' - works for a-zA-Z
repeat : '(' LETTERKEYS 'r' INTEGER ')'; - works for a-zA-Z
```

But I fail with

```
repeat : '(' LETTERSandDIGITKEYS INTEGER ')' - fails on '(a 5 r5)'
repeat : '(' LETTERSandDIGITKEYS 'r' INTEGER ')'; - fails on '(a 5 r5)'
```

Maybe the grammar can't do the recognition; maybe I need to recognize all the 5's keys in the same way (as KEYS or DIGITS or INTEGERS) and in the parse tree visitor interpret the middle DIGIT instances as keys, and the last set of DIGITS as an INTEGER count?

Is it possible to define a grammar that allows me to repeat digit keys as well as letter keys so that expressions like `(a 5 123 r5)` will be recognized correctly? (That is, "repeat keys a,5,1,2,3 five times.") I'm not tied to that specific syntax, although it would be nice to use something similar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the parse fails on the middle 5 because it can't tell if the 5 is an INTEGER or a KEY.

If you have defined the following rules:

```
INTEGER : [0-9]+;
KEY     : [a-zA-Z0-9];
```

then a single digit, like `5` in your example, will always become an `INTEGER` token. Even if
the parser is trying to match a `KEY` token, the `5` will become an `INTEGER`. There is nothing
you can do about that: this is the way ANTLR's lexer works. The lexer works in the following way:

1. try to consume as many characters as possible (the longest match wins)
2. if 2 or more rules match the same characters (like `INTEGER` and `KEY` in case of `5`), let the rule defined first "win"

If you want a `5` to be an `INTEGER`, but sometimes a `KEY`, do something like this instead:

```
key     : KEY | SINGLE_DIGIT | R;
integer : INTEGER | SINGLE_DIGIT;
repeat  : R integer;

SINGLE_DIGIT : [0-9];
INTEGER      : [0-9]+;
R            : 'r';
KEY          : [a-zA-Z];
```

and in your parser rules, you use `key` and `integer` instead of `KEY` and `INTEGER`.

Comment: Thank you - your examples were helpful for insight. If I understand correctly, 5,6,7 in `(a 5 6 7 r 5)` will be recognized as keys (via the SINGLE_DIGIT rule) because "key" is the first rule that matches. The 5 in `r 5` will match an integer in the repeat rule because the repeat rule produces the longest match. Is that correct? It is very interesting to see how you make an integer = INTEGER or SINGLE_DIGIT, where SINGLE_DIGIT is defined first to "win."

Comment: @Kevin you must realize the two point from my answer only apply to lexer rules, not parser rules. So, `r` becomes an `R` token, not a `KEY`(rule #2 applies here). And `12` becomes a `INTEGER` and not two `SINGLE_DIGIT`s (rule #1 applies).

Answer (score 0):

You can split your grammar into two parts. One to be the lexer grammar, one to be the parser grammar. The lexer grammar splits the input characters into tokens. The parser grammar uses the string of tokens to parse and build a syntax tree. I work on Tunnel Grammar Studio (TGS) that can generate parsers with this two ABNF (RFC 5234) like grammars:

```
key         = 'a'-'z' / 'A'-'Z' / '0'-'9'
repeater    = 'r' 1*('0'-'9')
```

That is the lexer grammar that has two rules. Each character that is not processed by the lexer grammar, is converted to a token, made from the character itself. Meaning that `a` is a `key`, `r11` is a `repeater` and `(` for example will be transferred to the parser as a token `(`.

```
document    = *ws repeat
repeat      = '(' *ws *({key} *ws) [{repeater} *ws] ')' *ws
ws          = ' ' / %x9 / %xA / %xD
```

This is the parser grammar, that has 3 rules. The `document` rule accepts (recognizes) white space at first, then one `repeat` rule. The `repeat` rule starts with a scope, followed by any number of white space. After that is a list of keys maybe separated by white space and after all keys there is an optional repeater token followed by optional white space, closing scope and again optional white space. The white space is `space` `tab` `carriage return` and `line feed` in that order.

The runtime of this parsing is linear for both the lexer and the parser because both grammars are LL(1). Bellow is the generic parse tree from the TGS online laboratory, where you can run this grammars for input `(a 5 r5)` and you will get this tree:

[image: generic syntax tree made by Tunnel Grammar Studio]

If you want to have more complex `key`, then you may use this:

```
key = 1*('a'-'z' / 'A'-'Z' / '0'-'9')
```

In this case however, the `key` and `repeater` lexer rules will both recognize the sequence `r7`, but because the `repeater` rule is defined later it will take precedence (i.e. overwrites the previous rule). With other words `r7` will be a `repeater` token, and the parsing will still be linear. You will get a warning from TGS if your lexer rules overwrite one another.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I see you included a screenshot of my exact `(a 5 r 5)` example - thank you for your effort. I admit I had to "up my game" to understand everything you wrote here, and for that I am thankful. I think both answers here have steered me in the right direction on how to formulate key and integer and single-digit rules.

Comment: You are welcome. If you want to have a space between the `r` and `5` you will need another grammar(s).